# Is it possible to simulate an EEPROM with the STM32 F446RE chip?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, eeprom

I looked through the STM32 F446RE datasheet and was unable to find a way for the chip to keep persistent data values for when it is turned on and off, or when reset.

The only alternative I can think of is adding a USB stick to it, which I am currently looking into if there are no better options.

Edit: I am using the STM32CubeIDE to program the F446RE Nucleo board.

Edit2: The amount of data needed to be persistent is several hundred characters (unfortunately I think it is possible that this can change. I hope it doesn't.) Basically monitoring a status of a mechanical system (I am not sure what that system is, but that is an developing issue). And it needs to be read/write in real-time.

Comment: Have you considered using the internal Flash?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @user34060 I am currently trying to attach a USB drive and have the microcontroller write/read it, but I don't know if that is a viable option. I know that the F446RE has an Embedded Flash memory (512kb) where it stores programs, but I am not sure if I can use/access that to store data.

Comment: @brhans For F446RE internal flash, I am seeing Embedded Flash memory that is separate and another for the Arm Cortex-M4 chip itself. I am not seeing any indications that they could be used like EEPROM and honestly I am not even sure how they can be accessed.

Comment: looks like you can just use flash on this part.  multiple banks.  simple.

Comment: there is no such thing as an arm cortex-m4 chip.  arm does not make chips.

Comment: the part in question is an st chip. that they chose to buy some arm ip as well as possibly buying other ip as well and including some of their own ip.  and most likely gluing it all together with their own ip.   arm has nothing to do whatsoever with flash.  could put whatever core you want in there and the chip (and high level code) doesnt necessarily chnage (as with the number of cortex-m based chips that now have risc-v cores instead).

Comment: @JohnSmith Seems like you may have missed telling us how much EEPROM memory you want to simulate. How much?

Comment: There are open source libraries which use Flash to simulate EEPROM.

Comment: @periblepsis Not a lot, I would say several hundred characters at most. The issue comes from that they will constantly be changing in real time.

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm using and enjoying the FRAM versions of the MSP430. In general FRAM may be perfect four what you are doing.

Comment: Please add important information like size and change rate by [edit]ing your question. Comments are not for such, as it is not expected and will be overseen.

Comment: How many times per second do you want to write the data? How frequently are the "readers" looking at the data? How many readers are there? Please answer these questions by drawing a detailed diagram with one box for microcontroller, and one box for each reader (event observer), and one box each for whatever you are observing with arrows showing flow of data in and out of flash (or USB stick). You're leaving so much out that we can't answer you -- most importantly, why are you doing this? Logging, debugging, networking (communications)? Please, improve your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. ST has an application note and example library to emulate EEPROM with the Flash memory.

Depending on your needs, i.e. how much memory you need, how often you need to change it, etc, you can use the flash with EEPROM emulation or the flash directly.

But since you say they constantly change, it does not sound like EEPROM or Flash is what you need, not the internal or any external EEPROM or Flash, including USB sticks or SD cards.

Maybe battery backed SRAM is what you need. The MCU has that already, you might only need to reconfgure your board with jumpers and add a battery.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it looks like FRAM may be a good solution for you. It comes in chip form, is a kind of external memory, sort of like EEPROM, but much faster, almost as fast as ram, hence its name. It comes in I2C or SPI interfaces, so should not be that hard to hook up and use. And it has extremely high endurance, so constantly writing to it shouldn't wear it out anytime soon. (Still do the calculations, of course, if it's any kind of serious usage).

Since you want to be able to read and write constantly and quickly, it looks like the SPI interface parts are faster. The [1897 breakout board](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adafruit-industries-llc/1897/4990785) which probably contains a 20MHz [MB85RS64VPNF-G-JNERE1 chip](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kaga-fei-america-inc/MB85RS64VPNF-G-JNERE1/4022654), (but you may be able to upgrade to the [33MHz version MB85RS64VYPNF-GS-BCE1](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kaga-fei-america-inc/MB85RS64VYPNF-GS-BCE1/13539965) by swapping out the chip), contains 8KB of non-volatile FRAM, and is made by Adafruit, so the documentation and support is usually pretty good.

---

[image]

---

It shouldn't be too hard to interface this breakout board, using SPI, to your F446RE Nucleo board.

Comment: Full disclosure -- I am not at all related to Adafruit, or anyone there, nor ST Microelectronics, and have absolutely nothing to profit from anything represented here.